# PHP IF is not with multiple AND

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a logic problem here with my if else statement.

If URL is not the same as newurl AND if newurl is not Array AND if NEWURL is not notfound than do this ....

This isn't working and I don't know where the logic is wrong here.

NEWURL is Array i.e. but the script still takes this if instead of the else.

To be more clear, the value is **just the word Array**. Sorry for the confusion.

```
 if (($url != $newurl) && ($newurl != "Array") && ($newurl != 'notfound')) { dothis } else{ dothat }
```

Comment: `Array` and `"Array"` are different things

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need is_array

```
if (($url != $newurl) && !is_array( $newurl ) && ($newurl != 'notfound')) { dothis } else{ dothat }
```

PHP returns at an echo the type of a var as a String, but you cant compare the var as string, because it isnt a string. It would be the same as a string with "Array" as content. So you have for every type a function. is_array, is_string etc... or you can get the type as String with gettype( $var )

http://php.net/manual/de/function.is-array.php

http://php.net/manual/de/function.gettype.php

Comment: I strongly recommend to use !== instead of !=. And also your solution is almost right if the dev  checks the type of the $newUrl and matching as type array. But wrong, if he checks the name of that. It's not properly clarified  in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably better to do a  new functions for this, which makes your code easy to read in the case if your check the type of the $newUrl:

```
function isValidUrl($newUrl, $url) {
        return (($url !== $newUrl) && !is_array($newUrl) && ($newUrl !== 'notfound'));
    }

if (isValidUrl($newUrl, $url)) {
    dothis 
} else{ 
    dothat 
}
```

Secondly, better if you not only check equality but also identity as well, so instead of using '!='  use '!==' which validates the types too.

However, if you wanted to check the is the url name matching 'Array' as a  string not as a type your code should work.
If you wanted to check  the type or the newUrl, you should use is_array();

And if you want to see clean code, it's better to naming the whole validation somehow like 'isValid', and then just checking that.